# ¿Cómo solucionar el error uncaught MercadoPagoException?

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, wordpress-plugin

mi web estaba funcionando correctamente y ahora tengo un error faltal al ingresar, SOLO cuando activo el plugin de mercado pago (si renombro la carpeta, puedo acceder completo a la web) 
No hice nada diferente, solo dejó de funcionar y muestra ese error, desactivé el plugin, accedí a mi cpanel y luego pude descargar la última versión del plugin y al activarlo.... mismo resultado....

Versión de WooCommerce; Versión 3.4.4 |
Vesión de Worpress: Versión 4.9.8
Versión de PHP: Versión Actual de PHP:  7.0
Versión del módulo, si está utilizando: Versión 3.0.17 
https://essocialweb.cl/clientes/tienda

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught MercadoPagoException: Could not resolve host:
>   api.mercadopago.com in
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php:848
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php(946):
>   MPRestClient::exec(Array, '3.0.17') #1
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/woocommerce-mercadopago.php(536):
>   MPRestClient::get(Array, '3.0.17') #2
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/woocommerce-mercadopago.php(131):
>   WC_Woo_Mercado_Pago_Module::get_categories() #3
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/woocommerce-mercadopago.php(123):
>   WC_Woo_Mercado_Pago_Module->__construct() #4
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   WC_Woo_Mercado_Pago_Module::init_mercado_pago_class('') #5
>   /home/essocial in
>   /home/essocial/public_html/clientes/tienda/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php
>   on line 848

Comment: Intentaste eliminar la carpeta del plugin por completo?

Comment: en el dia de hoy me ocurrio lo mismo, alguien sabe que ocurre con el modulo de Mercado Pago? no es la primera vez que nos pasa que se cae el sitio por este modulo.

Comment: posiblemente se haya dado una actualizacion en el backend del servidor de mercado pago, recomiendo consultar las api's de dicho servicio

Comment: gracias! he visto que hubo una actualización, pero tampoco funciona después de actualizar. Me ocurrió en varios proyectos, siempre hay un tiempo de adaptación entre el modulo de mercado pago y woocommerce me parece

Comment: Hola, si eliminé la carpeta pro completo, desintalé el pluggin, instalé la nueva versión y nada....

Comment: Esto me lo escribieron desde el área de soporte...

¡Hola! 

En Mercado Pago siempre buscamos optimizar nuestra plataforma ofreciendo la mayor capacidad y seguridad en el procesamiento de pagos.

Tu problema se debe principalmente a que tu aplicación intenta conectarse con una conexión poco segura.

¿Cómo puedo chequear si mi tienda WooCommerce es compatible con TLS 1.2?

(sigue en el siguiente comentario)

Comment: Podés encontrarlos en el admin de WordPress, yendo a WooCommerce > Status, y navegando hasta la sección de “Server environment”. 
PHP version: Tiene que ser 5.6 o superior
cURL version: Tiene que ser  7.34.0 o superior
OpenSSL version: Tiene que ser 1.0.1 o superior (puede encontrarse junto a cURL version)

En el caso de no cumplir con algunos de estos tres valores, contactá a tu proveedor de hosting inmediatamente y pediles una actualización. 

-----
Hice lo que me pidieron y mi web tiene todo lo que ellos piden, por ende cumple con lo que solicitan, no se que pasa entonces

Comment: si sos de argentina te recomiendo que comienses a trabajar con andreani y informas en la pasarela de pago que coloquen bien el correo electronico un correo electronico veraz donde corroborar la direccion del comprador... asi andreani envia el producto a la direccion informada por el cliente... ESO PIENSO HACER YO !! De nada y bendiciones !!